# NSTimer - Why does scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval work, yet initWithFireDate doesn't?

Tags: objective-c

This calls my selector repeatedly each 60 seconds as desired:

```
autoDeleteTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60 target:[SimpleDB class] selector:@selector(autoDelete:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

This next line doesn't call it at all. Not initially nor after 60 seconds:

```
autoDeleteTimer = [[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate: [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1] interval:60 target:[SimpleDB class] selector:@selector(autoDelete:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Can anyone explain why? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add the second timer to the main loop:

```
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer: autoDeleteTimer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

From the documentation of the method:

```
- (id)initWithFireDate:(NSDate *)date interval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds target:(id)target selector:(SEL)aSelector userInfo:(id)userInfo repeats:(BOOL)repeats
```

> Return Value:
>   The receiver, initialized such that, when added to a run loop, it will
>   fire at date and then, if repeats is YES, every seconds after that.
>
> You must add the new timer to a run loop, using addTimer:forMode:.
>   Upon firing, the timer sends the message aSelector to target. (If the
>   timer is configured to repeat, there is no need to subsequently re-add
>   the timer to the run loop.)

[NSTimer Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTimer/initWithFireDate%3ainterval%3atarget%3aselector%3auserInfo%3arepeats%3a)